# Change GtkSourceView contents on resize

Tags: resize, gtk, gtksourceview

I have a `GtkSourceView` widget with some text, it works fine.

I'd like to change the contents of the associated text buffer when the user resizes the view widget; I am having trouble doing this reliably. What is the preferred method?

The `SourceView` widgets are inside a `GtkPaned`, that can be resized either by the user moving the splitter, or when the container window changes size.

Comment: When the user resizes the _widget_ or the _window_? (You can't directly resize a widget, and widgets can resize as a result of more than just user interactions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the source view's `size-allocate` signal (with `g_signal_connect_after()`) and change the contents of the buffer at that point.